# How to ignore null in a sort, and use second column. Interleaved sort?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

Sql fiddle here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/36bAp4FK

Trying to sort like this:

First sort by unitloadsequencenumber, but if its null sort by the line_number

So the trip groups all of the order_numbers, an order_number can have multiple lines. The unitloadsequencenumber is the order it will be loaded onto a truck. So it sorts unitloadsequencenumber 1, then for the next line_number 2.0, and 3.0 of order_number ASDF-2

```
trip_id  order_number  line_number  model unitloadsequencenumber
1        ASDF-2             1.0            C     1
1        ASDF-2             2.0            A     [NULL]
1        ASDF-2             3.0            B     [NULL]
1        ASDF-2             4.0            A     2
1        ASDF-2             5.0            C     [NULL]
1        ASDF-1             1.0            C     3
1        ASDF-1             2.0            B     [NULL]

I have tried, but don't quite have it
```

SELECT *
FROM public.vendor_trips_detail
ORDER BY
COALESCE(unitloadsequencenumber, CAST(line_number AS FLOAT));

Comment: You will have to describe the desired order in some more detail.

Comment: Your result in the image (which should be plain text!) could simply be achieved with `ORDER BY line_number`. Please clarify your question, and provide text as text, not as image.

Comment: The `unitloadsequencenumber` looks totally unrelated to the desired output order. More like `ORDER BY order_number DESC, line_number ASC`?

Comment: gah, I'm sucking at explaining today. I tried to add a little more context for how it sorts first by unitloadsequencenumber and then line_number (if unitloadsequencenumber is null)